# How to filter columns in R regarding one column?

Tags: r, filter

I have this dataset in R:

[image]

And I want to filter the repeated values in "weather_description" everytime it occurs. However, it shouldn't be eliminated if it occurs again in the dataset, I only want to remove everytime this column has repeated values in this variable. The output should look like this:

```
2015-01-0101:00:00 sky is clear 1420070400
2015-01-0102:00:00 scattered clouds 1420074000
2015-01-0104:00:00 sky is clear 1420081200
```

Is there any simple way of doing this in R?

Comment: You wan't a simple group by or distinct across the 3 columns. Google dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

This is a base solution with aggregate:

```
aggregate(Time ~ .,df,head,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` per @CodeMonkey:

```
df %>%
mutate(grouper = cumsum(weather_description == lag(weather_description, default = first(weather_description)))) %>%
group_by(grouper) %>%
summarise(Time = first(time),
          weather_description = first(weather_description),
          timestamps = first(timestamps))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this solution in base r works for you:

**The data**

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c(as.Date(16436),as.Date(16437),as.Date(16437),as.Date(16437),
                          as.Date(16437),as.Date(16438),as.Date(16438),as.Date(16438),
                          as.Date(16438),as.Date(16439),as.Date(16439),as.Date(16439)), 
                 weather_description = c("sky is clear",
                                         "scattered clouds")[c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1)])
df
#         Time weather_description
#1  2015-01-01        sky is clear
#2  2015-01-02    scattered clouds
#3  2015-01-02    scattered clouds
#4  2015-01-02    scattered clouds
#5  2015-01-02    scattered clouds
#6  2015-01-03    scattered clouds
#7  2015-01-03    scattered clouds
#8  2015-01-03    scattered clouds
#9  2015-01-03    scattered clouds
#10 2015-01-04        sky is clear
#11 2015-01-04        sky is clear
#12 2015-01-04        sky is clear
```

**The function**

```
weather_changes <- function(dat){
  # split by weather description
  splitted <- split(dat, dat[,2])
  # for each, return only the first dates of a sequence
  byweather <- lapply(splitted, function(x) x[-which(c(0,ifelse(diff(x[,1])<2,1,0))==1),])
  # combine to a single data.frame
  newdf <- do.call(rbind, byweather)
  # order by date
  newdf <- newdf[order(newdf[,1]),]
  # remove the messy row names
  rownames(newdf) <- NULL
  newdf
}
weather_changes(df)
#        Time weather_description
#1 2015-01-01        sky is clear
#2 2015-01-02    scattered clouds
#3 2015-01-04        sky is clear
```